# How to change color of image in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there any API for changing image color directly in windows phone?

For a image like following?

[image]

Comment: You could transform your image as a path then change the brush color ?

Comment: @WarferA Can you explain with some sample code?

Comment: Check here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465055.aspx the difficult part will be to transform your image as a path. You can use Blend to do so.

Comment: @WarfarA This images are coming from Server, so I will not need to draw them.Just I want to change colour of Image

Answer (score 0):

You can make a black background and draw the image as transparent line. Save this as `png`. Now, put the image in a stackpanel and change the background of the stackpanel to your required color. This will produce the same result which you wanted. Hope this helped!